# Partial Not Defined in Jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Here is what I have in index.jade.
And yes I am using express.js

```
extends layout

block content
  h1 Invoices:
  != partial("invoice")
```

This matches what I see in every single Jade/Express tutorial. But I get "Reference error: partial not defined". Any ideas why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jade newest version doesn't support partials. You might be following outdated tutorials. Please read up on jade documentation [here](http://github.com/visionmedia/jade)

Comment: Wow, I thought I was perfectly safe by following official express.js guide

Comment: Express v3 is still beta, their docs haven't been updated yet. Check out [Migrating from 2.x to 3.x](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x).

Answer (score 16):

Use `include`, without quotes (This example is from the [jade documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade))

```
users = [{ name: 'Tobi', occupation: 'Ferret' }]

each user in users
  .user
    include invoice
```

Where `invoice` is your "partial" template.

Comment: The include will take the current context (in the above example, `invoice` will have access to the `user`), so you can pass parameters by creating a property bag for it.